# Adiabatic compression of an ideal monatomic gas. What would the change in entropy be?

Tags: physical-chemistry, entropy

Two moles of an ideal monatomic gas initially at 300K and a pressure of 2 atm is compressed adiabatically using a constant external pressure $P_{ext}$ until equilibrium is reached. The temperature of the gas is then 400K

a) calculate w, q, $\Delta U$, and $\Delta H$ for this process

b) calculate the final equilibrium pressure $P_f$ of the gas (note $P_f =P_{ext}$)

c) calculate $\Delta S$for this process.

a) I calculated $\Delta U$ by $\Delta U= nC_v\Delta T$. Since it is an ideal gas, the $C_v= \frac{3 }{2} R$. From that I got $2494.2$ J for $\Delta U$. Then, since it's adiabatic, q = 0, thus w = $2494.2$ J. I calculated $\Delta H$ using $nC_p\Delta T$. As $C_p$ would be $\frac{5}{ 2} R$, $\Delta H$ is $4157$ J.

b) I used the ideal gas law $V_2= \frac{nRT_2}{P_2} $and subbed it into $w= -P_{ext}(V_2-V_1)$ and as the question says$ P_f  (P_2)= P_{ext}$ I managed to eliminate some variables to end up with a $P_{ext}$ of 3.68 atm.

c) I don't know how to do this. I'm confused as to what formula to use for this. We can't use the $\frac{q_{rev}}{T}$ one since it doesn't state in the question if this is a reversible process. There are 2 other ones I learned, but they can only be used when it's isothermal or constant volume/constant pressure. They are:
[image]

[image]

Comment: You wrote "it doesn't state in the question if this is a reversible process".  Actually, you know it can't be reversible, because reversibility requires P_ext = P_int, while in this case, P_ext is a constant, yet P_int must be increasing.

Comment: Ah I see, however we still can't use Qrev/T since that formula can only be used for reversible processes. So I'm still wondering how to calculate delta S?

Comment: Go to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy and, from the Contents section, go to sec. 6.2 ( "Cooling and heating").  At the end of that section you will see more general equations that allow you to calculate delta_S  for processes involving an ideal gas in which either both T and V, or T and P, change.  You should also understand that, if your process *were* reversible, the fact that it's also adiabatic means delta_S would always be zero, because q_rev = 0.

Comment: Entropy is a state function so as long as you end up where you need to end up, you can choose how to get there, i.e. combine two processes for which you know the entropy change. https://memegen.link/custom/state_functions.../are_path--independent.jpg?alt=https://iili.io/H0DOYb.jpg